# Jfreechart Chartpanel zoomindomain ignores given coordinates

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I want to be able to zoomin/zoomout my chart around the point the mouse is currently pointing at. However, when I'm calling:

```
zoomInDomain(xScrollingCoord, yScrollingCoord);
```

the chart gets zoomed in, but zooming is centered around the centre of the chart, not the point the mouse is currently pointing at. The [official documentation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#zoomInDomain-double-double-) clearly states that the zoomin should be around the given coordinates, but that's not the case. Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?
Here's how I set the coordinates:

```
chartpanel.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            xScrollingCoord = e.getX();
            yScrollingCoord = e.getY();
            mouseHandlingController.handleMouseWheelMoved(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The handler owned by `ChartPanel` works; why not use it?

Comment: @trashgod I only want to be able to zoom with the scroll, not when dragging the mouse, which is the default behaviour. Do you know if it's possible to achieve what I want?

Comment: Ok, this [workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29602610/3165046) does the job.

Comment: I can close as duplicate or you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). If the latter, please also update the question to reflect the use case.